# Push notification delivers from local env, but not from server

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, pem, csr

I'm trying to get my server to deliver push notifications via Apple's Push Notification service. (APNs)

My setup is as follows:

- Cordova HTML/JS app
- API in Rails on VPS via https
- Houston gem for Push Notifications

I've created a certificate for development on my mac. When I run my server locally it successfully sends the notification to my iPhone.

I'm now trying to get it working on my server but without luck. I've generated a CSR locally, uploaded it in Apple's iOS App ID's editor and downloaded the CER. I then exported the CER to p12 with Keychain Access and converted that to a PEM file with the following command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in apn_production.p12 -out apn_production.pem -nodes -clcerts
```

Houston needs this PEM file to send push notifications, I've done the same for development and it worked, but it needs to send from a server now, which could be the problem, I don't get any errors though. The notifications just don't arrive, which could be a production/development mistake I'm making.

I also tried creating a CSR file on my server and upload that via the iOS App ID's editor, but when I download the CER and open it in Keychain Access I'm not able to export it to P12, only to CER, PEM and P7B. Also there isn't a private key in this file, which there is within my locally created development certificate. Also when I export it to PEM and use it with Houston on my server it throws an error that the certificate is invalid.

Another thing I tried was upload the CSR generated by my VPS on the Apple Push Certificates Portal. This throws an error mentioning the certificate is invalid.

There's a couple things I'm not sure of:

**1. Am I in development or production mode?**

The app is not yet in the app-store, but it is in beta mode to download via TestFlight and push notification need to be send from my server. Is this a production environment or development or do I need to define this manually somewhere before building the App?

**2. Is it possible to use a locally generated CSR for a PEM to be used on my server?**

Am I right that I need a server generated CSR to start with when I finally need a PEM to send push notifications with from my server?

**3. What do do now, how should I debug?**

The PEM generated from my locally generated CSR is now uploaded to my server and Houston doesn't throw errors whatsoever. The push notifications don't arrive though, so, what should I do, can I trace these push notifications somewhere? Is there some APN logfile which I can read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You need to use production certificates for sending push notifications via test flight.

2) You do not need a server generated CSR. You only need a valid ".pem" for sending push notification.

3) You need to remove sanbox (sandbox mode) from push notification url in push sending script. Also check if port 2195 of your server is open for communication or not because APNS communicates via this port.

Comment: Musad Thanks for the clear answer, I guess it's the port, let me check!

Comment: If it is the port issue, you can use a third party api like parse. Check https://parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications

Comment: I've opened port 2195, but it didn't seem to work. I'd rather use the standard APN instead of a third party solution. I will redo the whole thing today, see if that solves anything. One thing that will be difficult is that TestFlight and Xcode both export to the same app and both use my VPS as API. I develop in Chrome on my mac (HTML/JS) and this uses my local API, this way I don't need to build while developing. The difficult thing about this is that my server doesn't know if a device is in the production or development environment.

Comment: Got it to work in the end, don't know exactly what it was, but I used the development certificate generated locally like you suggested, opened up ports 2195, 2196 and 5223 on the server and this all from start, thanks again for your help!